# jquery highlight menu

Tags: jquery

I have this script that highlight the nav menu when clicked but after the click the selected class disappears. Is there a workaround in here to make the selected class in effect after the clicked?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( '#nav ul li a' ).click( function() {
        $( '#nav ul li' ).removeClass( 'selected' );
        $( this ).parent( 'li' ).addClass( 'selected' );
        alert('hello');
    });
});

</script>
    <div id="nav"> 
        <ul>    
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your code looks to me like it should work.  Can you provide more info?

Comment: from the above script I intentionally put alert('hello') to test that the clicked li is actually added with selected class and it was the problem is that after I clicked ok on alert box (the function exit) and highlighted li (style) disappears. Substituting the alert('hello') with 'return false' makes the highlighting works but going to next page does not work anymore as @gearsdigital pointed

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`.siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method to get the `li` elements which have the `selected` class.

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( "#nav ul li a" ).click( function() {
        $( this ).parent( "li" )
            .addClass( "selected" )
            .siblings( ".selected" )
                .removeClass( "selected" );
        return false;
    });
});
```

You can see this in action on [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zq3ZX/).

Comment: As note for the Author... with `return false` the link (go to new page) will not work anymore. But it seems this is not wanted in your example?

Comment: @gearsdigital, to comment on this: I added `return false` because I think that might have been the cause as to why the class was remove (the page reloaded on click).

Comment: @Marcus I know... :) My note was for the thread owner. It's not that clear it should be. Im also not sure what he want exactly to do... Normaly the best way to highlight the current menu item is a cms based solution. Without additional client site scripting or maybe jquery plugins he will never get the current item activ over all pages.

Comment: @gearsdigital, I was commenting your comment to shed some light on why I added `return false` for the author, not answering it ;)

Comment: @gearsdigital if the best way to highlight the current menu item is by using a cms solution then I would love to hear your ideas about it. BTW im using django.

Comment: @Marcus Ok :) @Ronz I've no experience with Django but i'am pretty sure you will find some mechanism wich highlights the current page. Maybe this is what you're looking for: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2143/ On same page you'll find some addiontional Jquery enabled solutions http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/435/ or another on server side http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/429/

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly... Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jgmgW/

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
   $( '#nav ul li' ).click( function() {
       $( '#nav ul' ).children('li').removeClass();
      $( this ).addClass( 'selected' );
   });
});

#nav .selected a{background:red;display:block}

<div id="nav">
    <ul>    
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```